# How would Bitcoin’s cryptography change?

Tags: security, blockchain-fork, cryptography

Let’s say, that 20 years ahead, Bitcoin’s crypto is not considered secure anymore. More precisely, the key length is too short for it to be safe, be it the hash functions or public key cryptography. What would our options be?

Could we simply increase the key length for the wallets and make that mandatory? Would that be a hard fork?
Or could we just use a soft fork and advise users to switch to a new more secure wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a hard fork, and a difficult one to develop at that.

Comment: Thank you! But I am right in thinking, that this would be the only way to ensure that Bitcoin would stay secure in that case, right?